# Easy IDEA sharing of JS code between different JS projects?

Tags: javascript, java, reactjs, npm, bower

I want to share common JS code between different JS projects in a very easy way.
I thought about creating a Bower component (see: [LINK](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29002979/how-to-share-code-between-multiple-projects-with-angularjs)) or a private NPM component (see: [LINK](https://docs.npmjs.com/private-modules/intro)).

However, I want it to be used in a very IDE friendly way. A such, that when we update the Common code (project) we don't need to first publish the changed Common code.

Let me explain what I mean by how we do this in Java with Eclipse (we use mostly IntelliJ with Python and React JS currently): In a Java project we include Common Java code through a maven dependency, and also open the Common Java code as a project in Eclipse. Eclipse is then smart enough to see that it will include a direct link to the Common code project, instead of including the Common code as jar such that you don't need to first deploy the Common code project to the private repo when making changes to it.

We aren't experts in JS code yet, so how can we realise this same kind of friendly IDE usage with JS ?

Comment: Would package.json local paths work for you? https://docs.npmjs.com/files/package.json#local-paths

Comment: Yes, thanks, I thought about a similar construction using webpack Alias, as we use Webpack. But is that the way to go? How are others setup such a development environment?

Comment: Any experience with using npm module "local-dependencies"?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved it by using npm-link:

1) Used npm-link as explained here: [LINK](http://justjs.com/posts/npm-link-developing-your-own-npm-modules-without-tears)

2) Solved the babel problem as explained here: [LINK](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34574403/how-to-set-resolve-for-babel-loader-presets/)
In my case, my babel config looks like:

```
                options: {
                    presets: ['babel-preset-es2015', 'babel-preset-react'].map(require.resolve),
                    plugins: ['babel-plugin-transform-react-jsx-img-import'].map(require.resolve) 
                }
```

Works pretty wel. I looked at npm local-dependencies, but it didn't work with the current npm version. Currently it does as they fix it. But I always have to run "npm start" just like other sync npm modules. Neither do I want to use local dependencies as several developers put the shared code at different places, which make it fragil.